# Roles in Laravel aren't working as intended

Tags: laravel, roles

I've made by the book, roles for my laravel program. Problem occurs in one particular instance, one of methods in User model always "pop-up" ... Whatever user have for role_id, method always shows certain role's name, in this case "moderator". Don't know what is wrong with it, or at least i can't see it ...

Here is User model:

```php
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password',"avatar"
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];

        public function rola(){
            return $this->belongsTo("App\Roles", "id");
        }

        public function posts(){
            return $this->hasMany("App\Post");
        }

        public function comments(){
            return $this->hasMany("App\Comment");
        }

        public function isAdmin()
        {//dd($user);

            return $this->rola()->where('role', 'administrator');
        }

        public function isModerator()
        {//dd($user);

            return $this->rola()->where('role', 'moderator');
        }

        public function isUser()
        {//dd($user);

            return $this->rola()->where('role', 'user');
        }

        public function isPeon()
        {//dd($user);

            return $this->rola()->where('role', 'peon');        
        }

}
```

Here is Roles model:

```php
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Roles extends Model
    {
        public function rola(){
            return $this->hasMany("App\User", "role_id");
        }
    }
```

And for example if just display in any view:

```php
    {{auth()->user()->rola->id}} <br> // 2 <- correct
    {{auth()->user()->role_id}} // 3 <- this should be 2 also.
```

Here is a image of my db schema:
[image: schema]

And image of roles table:
[image: roles]

By default, whenever new user get registered, it automatically receives role of "peon" which has id 4.
Not sure where my mistake lies, maybe i'm not seeing something ...

**Edit1:**

Here is a link to github [repo](https://github.com/codename11/SimpleForum-TicketingSystem) for those who want to take a gander at it.

Comment: `return $this->belongsTo("App\Roles", "id");` should probably use `role_id` for the relationship, not `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is in your `rola()` function in your **User.php** file: you are defining a foreign key to the `belongsTo` relationship which here is `id`.

It should be `role_id` as this is the key Eloquent would try to map to the `id` of the Roles' model. [See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) for more informations

Comment: It is! I saw, somewhere on SO, way of doing this(originally) and i'm guessing that first parameter of relation is model and second(for foreign keys) is name of the field in the current model that holds values of said foreign key? Is that correct? I.e. return $this->belongsTo(tableWhichholdsValueOfForeignKey, FieldInModelsTableThatConnectsToFirstParameterViaId); ?

Comment: Well I would also avoid to use many `isAdmin`, `isModerator` etc... I would suggest you to have only one `function isRole($roleName) { return $this->rola()->where('role', $roleName); }`

Comment: I saw this approach also. I wanted to try this simpler one just to be sure all relations, policies and all is by the book first. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 3):

To improve your application, don't use one function for each role you have.
Supposed you have 100 roles on roles table, with the current code, you will also need 100 functions like `isAdmin` or `isSomething`.

Add something like this:

```php
    public function hasRole($roleName)
    {
        return $this->rola()->where('role', $roleName);
    }

    /**
    * Check if the user has any of the given roles.
    */
    public function hasAnyRole(array $roleNames)
    {
        $userRole = $this->rola;
        return in_array($userRole->name, $roleNames);
    }
```

Now you can check for roles:

```php
    $user->hasRole('admin'); //If the user has the admin role, returns true. Otherwise returns false.
```

To check for roles on blade view:

```php
@if(Auth::check())
    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('role-name') || Auth::user()->hasRoles('another-role-name'))
        //Your markup here
    @endif
@endif
```

And for multiple roles:

```php
@if(Auth::check())
    @if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRoles(['role-name', 'another-role-name']))
        //Your markup here
    @endif
@endif
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: One question though ... How to implement that in view, for example i now have @if(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->isAdmin() || Auth::user()->isModerator())) //some markup @endif Possibly like this: Auth::user()->hasRole("administrator") ? How for multiple roles?

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you mean. I add your example to my answer. You want to check for roles like `@if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole(['admin', 'another-role'])) //some markup @endif` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `rola()` function.
You are using the wrong foreign key with the `belongsTo`. It should be `role_id`, not `id` (which it currently is).

Here is a code snippet with some improvements:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',"avatar"
    ];
     /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    */

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function rola(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Roles", "role_id");
        //Or just return $this->belongsTo(Roles::class);
    }

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Post");
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Comment");
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {//dd($user);
        return $this->hasRole('admin');
    }

    public function isModerator()
    {//dd($user);
       return $this->hasRole('moderator');
    }

    public function isUser()
    {//dd($user);
        return 
        return $this->hasRole('user');
    }

    public function isPeon()
    {//dd($user);
        return $this->hasRole('peon');
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return $this->rola->role === $role;
    }
}
```

I suggest you to rename your `rola` function within Roles model to `users`, since it return all users who has some role.

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Roles extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'role_id');
    }
}
```

One more thing: take a look at [this package](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-acl). It really helps you to works with users, permissions and permission groups.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Roles table doesn't have an "user_id". User table has role_id. Only way it can connect is by referencing id field of particular user ... nevermind ... You're right except i don't have from |roleToUser|, but only from "UserToRole" ... Although, it is very helpful finding all users with particular role ...

Comment: It is now edited. To be honest, I did not notice that I changed the foreign key when I answered the question. But also rename your function, it's a good practice issue.

Comment: Add one new function to your `User` model, called `hasAnyRole`. The function receives an array of `role names`, and check if this array contains the currently user role.